# Unable to fetch napping. Do you have indices matching the pattern?

Tags: linux, elastic-stack

I am facing the error following:

> Unable to fetch napping. Do you have indices matching the pattern?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 Version. My ip is 192.168.100.93.

Here are my configurations. Here I tested elasticsearch and the result is:

```
root@IT-PC:/etc/logstash/conf.d# curl -X GET http://localhost:9200


  {
          "name" : "Isaiah Bradley",
          "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
          "version" : {
            "number" : "2.3.5",
            "build_hash" : "90f439ff60a3c0f497f91663701e64ccd01edbb4",
            "build_timestamp" : "2016-07-27T10:36:52Z",
            "build_snapshot" : false,
            "lucene_version" : "5.5.0"
          },
          "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
            }


         root@IT-PC:/etc/logstash/conf.d# sudo nano 01-inputs.conf
                #tcp syslog stream via 5140
                input {
                  tcp {
                    type => "syslog"
                    port => 5140
                  }
                }
                #udp syslogs tream via 5140
                input {
                  udp {
                    type => "syslog"
                    port => 5140
                  }
                }

root@IT-PC:/etc/logstash/conf.d# sudo nano 10-syslog.conf

filter {
  if [type] == "syslog" {
    #change to pfSense ip address
    if [host] =~ /192\.168\.100\.93/ {
      mutate {
        add_tag => ["PFSense", "Ready"]
      }
    }
    if "Ready" not in [tags] {
      mutate {
        add_tag => [ "syslog" ]
      }
    }
  }
}
filter {
  if [type] == "syslog" {
    mutate {
      remove_tag => "Ready"
    }
  }
}
filter {
  if "syslog" in [tags] {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%$
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
      add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
    }
    syslog_pri { }
    date {
      match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM  dd HH:mm:ss" ]
      locale => "en"
    }
    if !("_grokparsefailure" in [tags]) {
      mutate {
        replace => [ "@source_host", "%{syslog_hostname}" ]
        replace => [ "@message", "%{syslog_message}" ]
      }
    }
    mutate {
      remove_field => [ "syslog_hostname", "syslog_message", "syslog_timestamp" ]
    }
#    if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] {
#      drop { }
#    }
  }
}
```

This is the 30-outputs.conf file and its contents:

```
root@IT-PC:/etc/logstash/conf.d# sudo nano 30-outputs.conf
                output {
                elasticsearch {

                hosts => localhost

                index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}" }
                # stdout { codec => rubydebug }
                }
```

I don't know where I did mistakes. Otherwise send some URL except Digital Ocean to install ELK properly.